# MySQL AES_ENCRYPTION Slowing Down Performance

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, encryption, aes

I'm hosting a port forwarded server on my computer. For a school assignment, I am trying to make a login page on my computer.

I set up my database and `PHP` script to validate my passwords and everything using `AES_ENCRYPT()` and `AES_DECRYPT()`.

In Chrome, I launched the actual `PHP` script on localhost and the response performance I got for validating some sample data was excellent (the table has barely five rows right now).

However, in the actual site, I need to access this script using an `AJAX` request. As soon as I submit the request, the website freezes, and I have to close out the tab and try all over again (the tab doesn't refresh).

Why is this happening? I am using the `POST` method to send my data.

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? Is it MySQL or PHP that is doing the hashing?

Comment: MySQL is doing the hashing. PHP is 5.6 and MySQL is 5.0+

Comment: PHP version 5.5 and newer has functions for dealing with the hashing of passwords. Let PHP deal with the hashing of the passwords